# SQL query to get specific rows based on one value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ID        Place          Name                Type              Count
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7718    | UK1   |  Lemuis           | ERIS TELECOM          | 0
7713    | UK1   |  Astika LLC       | VERIDIAN              | 34
7712    | UK1   |  Angel Telecom AG | VIACLOUD              | 34
7710    | UK1   |  DDC S.r.L        | ALPHA UK              | 25
7718    | UK1   |  Customers        | WERTS                 | 0
```

Basically I have a variable and I want to compare that variable the the `'Type'` column. If the variable matches the type then I want to return all the rows that have the same ID as the variable's ID.

For example, my variable is `'ERIS TELECOM'`, I need to retrieve the ID for `'ERIS TELECOM'` which is `7718`. Then I search the table for rows that have the `ID 7718`.

My desired output should be:

Table Name: `FullResults`

```
ID        Place          Name                Type              Count
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7718    | UK1   |  Lemuis           | ERIS TELECOM          | 0
7718    | UK1   |  Customers        | WERTS                 | 0
```

Is there a query that will do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM FullResults
WHERE ID = (SELECT ID 
            FROM FullResults
            WHERE Type= @variable);
```

I guess it will be something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick, returns all data for all ID's that have a matching type.

```
SELECT *
 FROM Table
WHERE ID
   IN (SELECT ID from Table where Type = 'ERIS TELECOM')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stored procedure for this where you will pass a variable while executing the stored procedure.

```
create proc dbname.dbo.usp_get_date_from_type_value 
(
   @type_value varchar(50)
 )
as
begin

       select ID, Place, Name, Type, Count
       from dbname..table
       where ID in (select ID from dbname..table where type = @type_value)

end
```

Then you can run the following statement.

```
Exec  dbname.dbo.usp_get_date_from_type_value @type_value = 'ERIS TELECOM'
```